# Cannot open or reach Windows Device Portal in Windows IOT Core

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub, windows-10-iot-core, windows-iot-core-10

I want to try config and access my raspberry pi using "windows 10 iot" on it, and using Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard" on my PC. So, i can see my board on "connected devices", also I have an IP and a port number, like: http://169.254.94.240:8080, but when I try to open this on browser, nothing happens (Show the message "It's not possible to access this site"). There is a cable to connect the Raspberry pi and the PC with the router.But i can connect through HDMI, the IOT core OS running Perfectly.Any solution for this, 
 What i supposed to do?
Using Device : Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.2 model 2015

Comment: Have you checked if there is a filter in the router, or a firewall rule to block the port in your PC?

Comment: Yes, when i connect my PC to raspberry pi the automatically one IP will assigned, then the Device Portal is reached, After that, i can change my IP address manually in My PC then the device portal cannot reached

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when the device can show in the IoT Dashboard device list,but you could not access the device portal, I think you can try with following steps.

1. Open the device portal from IoT Dashboard.
   [image]
2. Trying to ping the device to make sure if the ip address of device is correct or reachable.
3. Check if there is some rule configured in the router or there is some filter to block the ip and port in your PC.

Comment: Yes, when i connect my PC to raspberry pi the automatically one IP will assigned, then the Device Portal is reached, After that, i can change my IP address manually in My PC then the device portal cannot reached

Comment: When you changed the IP address, did you try to ping the device? After the IP address changed, you need to reboot the device.

Comment: Sure, after changing my IP address, reboot my device then ping from CMD, it will get response, but cannot connect device portal and i tried to deployed samples from Dashboard successfully, but i can tried deploy from Visual Studio 2019(Administrator) - cannot find IP address error.

Comment: Please try to clear the cache of your explorer or use another explorer to view the device portal.